# How to abbreviete logger name?

Tags: nlog

Is there a way to abbreviate logger name in target's layout? I want to shorten long logger names, eg. instead of `com.logback.Foobar` I would like to have `c.l.Fobar`.

This is very often in Java world. For example `logback` has such [abbreviator](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/4dd08e68321548cd85251ec389f5a832505e1268/logback-classic/src/test/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/TargetLengthBasedClassNameAbbreviatorTest.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not built in NLog, however you could easily add it.

For example:

```cs
//Register ${abbr-loggername}
LayoutRenderer.Register("abbr-loggername", (logEvent) => todo.Abbr(logEvent.LoggerName));
```

See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

You need for this the `LoggerName` property in the `LogEventInfo` object (see [API  docs](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/P_NLog_LogEventInfo_LoggerName.htm))